# Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server

Tags: php, html, apache, config, wampserver

Using wampserver and receiving this error:

> Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.

Google doesn't seem to have any solutions that work. Any ideas?

```
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:02 2011] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:02 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Child process is running
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:02 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Acquired the start mutex.
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:02 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:02 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:40 2011] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:40 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Mon Jul 25 19:07:41 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Released the start mutex
[Mon Jul 25 19:08:05 2011] [notice] Child 5828: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Jul 25 19:08:05 2011] [notice] Child 5828: Child process is exiting
[Mon Jul 25 19:08:05 2011] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
```

Comment: tell me if you need more information as I don't know what information is relevant.

Comment: More information required: why is this a problem?  What were you doing when you got this error / informational message; and what do you want to achieve (cancel the shutdown?)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Apache error log.

This error almost always occurs when another user shuts down a multi-user server. The Apache error log will tell you what happened so we can help if there are further issues.

**Edit**

Try this- go to `C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc` and make sure you have the following in `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Restart WAMP, and see if anything has changed.

Comment: I've been staring at these logs all day. I'm adding what seems to be relevant coz these are what's added when I restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. So, I quit the skype and run the wamp as administrator it works. After that I changed the skype listen port to 88. Now the wamp works fine.

Its the port conflict. So, either you may change the localhost port to 88 in httpd.config file.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by own stupidity, like in my case:

I've had a script on my server (Windows 2008 R2) that was configured to run every 5 minutes. It contained the following two lines:

```
net stop Apache2.4
net start Apache2.4
```

Strange enough this script was present for years and did never cause any remarkable effect for my websites. Only recently, Uptime Robot detected some downtimes.

To be honest, I don't know anymore why I had this script configured at all.

**Solution:**

To solve this, I simply deactivated the script in the Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been messing with your httpd.conf file? I was messing with mine, and changed the first "listen" bit to Listen 8080 and got rid of a the 303 error and am able to start apache. Now I have a 404 error...which is an improvement I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have both iis and wamp installed on my windows machine, and accidentally I have opened iis for port 80, which caused the error you have experienced.
Either change the port that Wamp listens to, either the port the IIS listens to